# .htaccess SetEnv set PHP $_SERVER variable to nested array

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, setenv

I am using PHP 5.6.22 and Apache 2.4.18. I have a `$_SERVER` variable that I want to set to be a nested array.

To clarify, at the beginning of my PHP script, I want `$_SERVER['key']` to be set to a two-level array as shown below:

```
$_SERVER['key'] = array('index' => array('sub_index' => 'some_value'))
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Environment variables are accessible via the `$_ENV` super global variable, not via `$_SERVER`.

Comment: what are index and sub_index? I assume you don't want to just put the code you just wrote at the top of your script?

Comment: No, I don't want that array verbatim but an array of that exact structure. The exact index names shouldn't matter

Comment: @arkascha SetEnv sets variables in $_SERVER. I'm actively seeing this in my script, and the Magento framework is built on that premise

Comment: I'd say that depends on _how_ you integrate php into the apache environment. Relying on that will make your code non portable.

Comment: I'm beholden to the Magento framework's architecture unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `myenv.php` with this code:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['key'] = array('index' => array('sub_index' => 'some_value'));
?>
```

Then add this line in your site root .htaccess:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file myenv.php
```

Now this data will be populated in `$_SERVER` before loading of any `.php` file.

[Read more about `auto_prepend_file`](https://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen `PUTENV` and `GETENV` using `json_***` functions, like:

```
$my_array= array( 'a'=>14, 'b'=>5);
PUTENV("my_namee=".json_encode($my_array));

.....
$var = json_decode(GETENV("my_namee"));
```